# Converting gaussian to histogram

Tags: python, normalization, normal-distribution

I'm running a model of particles, and I want to have initial conditions for the particle locations mimicking a gaussian distribution.
If I have `N` number of particles on 1D grid from -10 to 10, I want them to be distributed on the grid according to a gaussian with a known mean and standard deviation. It's basically creating a histogram where each bin width is 1 (the x-axis of locations resolution is 1), and the frequency of each bin should be how many particles are in it, which should all add up to `N`.

My strategy was to plot a gaussian function on the x-axis grid, and then just approximate the value of each point for the number of particles:

```
def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return 1./(np.sqrt(2.*np.pi)*sig)*np.exp(-np.power((x - mu)/sig, 2.)/2)

mean = 0
sigma = 1

x_values = np.arange(-10, 10, 1)
y = gaussian(x_values, mean, sigma)
```

However, I have normalization issues (the sum doesn't add up to `N`), and the number of particles in each point should be an integer (I thought about converting the `y` array to integers but again, because of the normalization issue I get a flat line).

Usually, the problem is fitting a gaussian to histogram, but in my case, I need to do the reverse - and I couldn't find a solution for it yet. I will appreciate any help!
Thank you!!!

Comment: What code are you using for plotting the histogram? Also, the number of particles in a bin will correspond to the *area under the gaussian* in the bin, not the height of the gaussian at the center of the bin (of course, those will be proportional in the limit as the bin width gets very small, but that's not the case here).

Comment: You are right, the number of particles is the area under the curve! In my case ```dx = 1``` so it should be the same. However, I still need to adjust the gaussian function to be normalized according to the number of particles. I don't have a specific code for the histogram yet because I couldn't figure out the normalization part yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.random.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) to sample this distribution. You can get `N` points inside range `(-10, 10)` that follows Gaussian distribution with the following code.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10000
mean = 5
sigma = 3

bin_edges = np.arange(-10, 11, 1)
x_values = (bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1]) / 2


points = np.random.normal(mean, sigma, N * 10)
mask = np.logical_and(points < 10, points > -10)
points = points[mask]  # drop points outside range
points = points[:N]  # only use the first N points
y, _ = np.histogram(points, bins=bin_edges)


plt.scatter(x_values, y)
plt.show()
```

The idea is to generate a lot of random numbers (10 N in the code), and ignores the points outside your desired range.

Comment: Thank you! I like your approach! The only thing missing is that the final ```y``` array should add up to the number of particles, sort of normalizing the histogram.

Comment: Hi @ValientProcess sorry now the code will give correct normalisation. I edited it so that we will firstly sample 10N points (rather than N).